# How to address java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError and java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when running cucumber script through Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, cucumber-java

I have a cucumber and selenium test which has always worked fine and suddenly stops running with the below error.

```
1 Scenarios (1 failed)
14 Steps (14 skipped)
0m0.004s

    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector.newInstance(AbstractInjector.java:145)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:342)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:678)
        at cucumber.runtime.java.picocontainer.PicoFactory.getInstance(PicoFactory.java:40)
        at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaHookDefinition.execute(JavaHookDefinition.java:60)
        at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHookIfTagsMatch(Runtime.java:224)
        at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHooks(Runtime.java:212)
        at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runBeforeHooks(Runtime.java:202)
        at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:40)
        at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.run(CucumberFeature.java:165)
        at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:122)
        at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:36)
        at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:18)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.optal.browsers.WebDriverFactory.createAndSetUpThreadedBrowser(WebDriverFactory.java:56)
        at com.optal.browsers.WebDriverFactory.create(WebDriverFactory.java:37)
        at com.optal.hooks.ScenarioHooks.<clinit>(ScenarioHooks.java:19)
        ... 24 more

    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.optal.hooks.ScenarioHooks
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector.newInstance(AbstractInjector.java:145)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:342)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:678)
        at cucumber.runtime.java.picocontainer.PicoFactory.getInstance(PicoFactory.java:40)
        at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaHookDefinition.execute(JavaHookDefinition.java:60)
        at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHookIfTagsMatch(Runtime.java:224)
        at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHooks(Runtime.java:212)
        at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runAfterHooks(Runtime.java:206)
        at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:46)
        at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.run(CucumberFeature.java:165)
        at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:122)
        at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:36)
        at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:18)

Calling System.exit() ..................

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Please, add the test code as well.

Comment: Please share class where you are keeping Hooks code i.e. @ Before & @After

Comment: it starts to work again after recompiling runnerscuke class.

Answer (score 3):

### ExceptionInInitializerError

An [ExceptionInInitializerError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ExceptionInInitializerError.html) is thrown to indicate that an exception occurred during evaluation of a static initializer or the initializer for a static variable.

The [ExceptionInInitializerError](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-lang-exceptionininitializererror-how-to-handle-exception-initializer-error/) is thrown when the JVM attempts to load a new class. During the class loading procedure, all static variables and static initializers are being evaluated. A static initializer is a block enclosed within curly braces without having any name and return type, except having the keyword **`static`**.

An example of a static initializer:

```
import java.util.UUID;

class Example {

     private static String ID = null;

     static {
      ID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
     }
}
```

The static initializer is evaluated only once during the class loading procedure. Thus, a thrown exception in the evaluation of a static variable or initializer is wrapped into an `ExceptionInInitializerError`, in order for the JVM to indicate that the class could not be initialized and loaded.

An example that throws `ExceptionInInitializerError` error is as follows:

```
public class Example {

     private static String message = null;
     private static String subMessage = null;

     public Example(String message) {
      Example.message = message;
     }

     static {
      /* Store the first 10 characters of the input message. */
      subMessage = message.substring(0, 10);
     }

     public String getSubMessage() {
      return subMessage;
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
      Example exampleClass = new Example("Test");
      System.out.println(exampleClass.getSubMessage());
     }
}
```

Executing the above code snippet you will see the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
     at main.java.Example.<clinit>(Example.java:13)
```

You can use either of the following methods to extract more information about the underlying actual exception:

- `getException()`: Returns the exception that occurred during a static initialization that caused this error to be created.
- `getCause()`: Returns the exception that caused this error to be thrown.

---

### Dealing with ExceptionInInitializerError

The `ExceptionInInitializerError` is used as a wrapper to indicate that an exception arises in the static initializer block or the evaluation of a static variable’s value. Thus, we have to ensure that the original exception is fixed, in order for the JVM to be able to load our class successfully.

---

### Outro

You can throw `unchecked` / `runtime` exceptions from the block of a static initializer. However, you cannot allow a checked exception to propagate out of a static block, because is not possible to handle these exceptions in your source.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Mac M1 chip and room lib , try this : In project-level build.gradle, add the following configuration in allprojects :

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    // ...
}

// ADD THE FOLLOWING
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.34.0'
    }
}
}
```

Ref : https://stackoverflow.com/a/70232822/7048025