# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:Last character in replacement string can't be \, character to be escaped is required

Tags: selenium

i am using sikuli with selenium WebDriver previously it was working fine but now its throwin exception `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError`
getting exception on this line `Screen sc =new Screen();` 
please help me

i have set envirnoment variable for sikuli and Using sikuli 1.1.0

```
public class RoleChangerInav {

WebDriver driver;

@Test
public void rolechanger() 
{
    try {


        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","D:\\CoxWorkspace\\iNAVieProject\\IEDriverServer_Win32_2.52.0\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        DesiredCapabilities ieCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();

        ieCapabilities.setCapability("nativeEvents", false);
        ieCapabilities.setCapability("unexpectedAlertBehaviour", "accept");
        ieCapabilities.setCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings", true);
        ieCapabilities.setCapability("disable-popup-blocking", true);
        ieCapabilities.setCapability("enablePersistentHover", true);
        ieCapabilities.setCapability("ignoreZoomSetting", true);
        ieCapabilities.setCapability("introduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings", true);
        ieCapabilities.setCapability("ie.ensureCleanSession", true);
        ieCapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.ENABLE_ELEMENT_CACHE_CLEANUP, true);

        ieCapabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
        //ieCapabilities.setPlatform(org.openqa.selenium.Platform.WIN10);

        ieCapabilities.setCapability("introduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings", true);
        ieCapabilities.setCapability("ie.ensureCleanSession", true);
        ieCapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.ENABLE_ELEMENT_CACHE_CLEANUP, true);


        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION, true);
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


        driver.get("URL");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.findElement(By.linkText("More information")).click();


        driver.navigate ().to ("javascript:document.getElementById('overridelink').click()");

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","IEDriverServer.exe");


        //Thread.sleep(2000);

        //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());

        WebElement userName = driver.findElement(By.name("j_username"));
        userName.sendKeys("888888");
        System.out.println("Username : 888888");

        WebElement passWord = driver.findElement(By.name("j_password"));
        passWord.sendKeys("*******");

        System.out.println("Password : ********");

        WebElement submit = driver.findElement(By.id("jadLoginBtn"));
        submit.click();

        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        alert.accept();

        Thread.sleep(12000);

        Screen sc =new Screen();



        Pattern clicksite=new Pattern("click_site.png");
        sc.wait(clicksite,2000);
        sc.click();
```

Comment: the title and the question doesn't match

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55950121/i-am-getting-java-lang-exceptionininitializererror-and-java-lang-noclassdeffound/55954254#55954254) helps you?