# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError using Selenium on win10 Eclipse & IntelliJ maven projs

Tags: java, windows, selenium-webdriver, maven-3, openjdk-17

Selenium WebDriver usage triggers Cannot initialize cryptographic mechanism at java.base/javax.crypto.JceSecurity on windows 10 machine for both Eclipse and IntelliJ Idea projects. Please guide/suggest on how to fix the error. I had setup this as maven project with JDK 17.0.2 and trying to execute a basic selenium test. I have checked thoroughly, there are no other versions of java installed on my machine.

[Click me for my java version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owdmV.png)

```
package testcase;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;

public class MyFristTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Testing the program!");
//      **WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();**
        WebDriver driver;
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\Softwares\\Selenium\\selenium-chrome-driver-4.1.2.jar");
        **driver = new ChromeDriver();**
        driver.get("https://www.zoho.com/");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sign in")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.findElement(By.id("login_id")).sendKeys("abc3@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='login']//button[@id='nextbtn']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='password']")).sendKeys("testing!23");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='login']//button[@id='nextbtn']")).click();
        driver.quit();
        
    }

}
```

Receiving same errors in both eclipse and IntelliJ.

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
```

and if I comment above line, I receive error for the below line

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:546)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLCipher.isTransformationAvailable(SSLCipher.java:511)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLCipher.<init>(SSLCipher.java:500)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLCipher.<clinit>(SSLCipher.java:82)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite.<clinit>(CipherSuite.java:65)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.getApplicableSupportedCipherSuites(SSLContextImpl.java:343)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$AbstractTLSContext.<clinit>(SSLContextImpl.java:556)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:375)
    at java.base/java.security.Provider$Service.getImplClass(Provider.java:1933)
    at java.base/java.security.Provider$Service.getDefaultConstructor(Provider.java:1964)
    at java.base/java.security.Provider$Service.newInstanceOf(Provider.java:1878)
    at java.base/java.security.Provider$Service.newInstanceUtil(Provider.java:1886)
    at java.base/java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1861)
    at java.base/sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:236)
    at java.base/sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:164)
    at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(SSLContext.java:185)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.JdkSslContext.<clinit>(JdkSslContext.java:74)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.newClientContextInternal(SslContext.java:824)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContextBuilder.build(SslContextBuilder.java:611)
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.ssl.DefaultSslEngineFactory.buildSslContext(DefaultSslEngineFactory.java:59)
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.ssl.DefaultSslEngineFactory.init(DefaultSslEngineFactory.java:74)
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.ChannelManager.<init>(ChannelManager.java:104)
    at org.asynchttpclient.DefaultAsyncHttpClient.<init>(DefaultAsyncHttpClient.java:92)
    at org.asynchttpclient.Dsl.asyncHttpClient(Dsl.java:32)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyClient.createHttpClient(NettyClient.java:105)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyClient.<clinit>(NettyClient.java:50)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyClient$Factory.createClient(NettyClient.java:146)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:107)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:94)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:85)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.<init>(DriverCommandExecutor.java:80)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriverCommandExecutor.<init>(ChromiumDriverCommandExecutor.java:35)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver$ChromeDriverCommandExecutor.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:118)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:106)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:93)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:48)
    at testcase.MyFristTest.main(MyFristTest.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Can not initialize cryptographic mechanism
    at java.base/javax.crypto.JceSecurity.<clinit>(JceSecurity.java:119)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Can't read cryptographic policy directory: unlimited
    at java.base/javax.crypto.JceSecurity.setupJurisdictionPolicies(JceSecurity.java:333)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.JceSecurity$1.run(JceSecurity.java:110)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.JceSecurity$1.run(JceSecurity.java:107)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.JceSecurity.<clinit>(JceSecurity.java:106)
    ... 38 more
```

Below is the POM used for Maven setup.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.ski</groupId>
    <artifactId>HybridFramework</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <selenium-java-version>4.1.2</selenium-java-version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.36</slf4j.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium-java-version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium-java-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.uncommons/reportng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.uncommons</groupId>
            <artifactId>reportng</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml-schemas -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

### ExceptionInInitializerError

[ExceptionInInitializerError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ExceptionInInitializerError.html) implies that an unexpected exception has occurred in a static initializer which indicates that an exception occurred during evaluation of a static initializer or the initializer for a static variable.

> You can find a detailed discussion in [How to address java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError and java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when running cucumber script through Selenium Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55954254/7429447)

---

### This usecase

Within the [*System.setProperty()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60061951/7429447) line the key *`webdriver.chrome.driver`* should be used to pass the absolute path of the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) binary/executable. So instead of passing `selenium-chrome-driver-4.1.2.jar` you need to pass *`chromedriver.exe`*.

---

### Solution

Effectively, your line of code will be:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe");
```

Comment: My issue got fixed when I uninstalled and reinstalled JDK 1.7.2 in my system. After reinstalling java in my machine it shows as below now... This fixed the issue. Thanks for your prompt response.                                                                  
C:\Users\Administrator>where java
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.2\bin\java.exe